# Highlight Current Page in Navigation Bar

Tags: jquery

I tried to give a shot at the problem posed in the subject line.  So below is my HTML and jQ for what I'm trying to accomplish.

html

```
<ul class="topnav1">
   <li class="highlight">
      <a  href="index.php">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a  href="testimonials_page.php">Testimonials</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="services.php">Services</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="contact_page.php">Contact  Us</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jQ

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Menu highlights.
$(document).ready(function(){
   var pathname =  (window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
   $(".topnav1 li a").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('href')==pathname) {
         $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
         $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
      }
   });
   $("li.highlight"').parents().each(function(){
      if ($(this).is("li")){
         $(this).addClass("highlight");
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

The idea is to remove the highlighted class from its default list item, and assign it to the list item whose href attribute matches the current url.  I must admit I'm not the best at programming matching patterns, so I'm kind of at a loss as to how to match only part of the url with the href attribute and I'm not sure that's why my code isn't working( the highlight is retained on the home menu item and isn't applied to the others). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// in real life use: var curURL = document.location.toString();
var curURL = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/testimonials_page.php';

$('.topnav1 li.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
$('.topnav1 li a').each(
    function(){
        if (curURL.indexOf(this.href) != -1){
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BkrVg/).

References:

- JavaScript, at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)'s [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) resource:

  - [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location).
  - [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.URL).
  - [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).
- jQuery, from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/):

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: your fiddle doesnt work.  when i click on the links, it redirects me to an error page.

Comment: That's because I used the links you posted. The demo will, therefore, link to external pages using the relative URL in those links. The point of the demo was to show how jQuery can find the link with the same URL as the current page, and designate that link as 'active. This means this script would have to run on each page that you link to (albeit happily within an external JS file).

Comment: Thanks. Your method worked.  Turns out, I failed to balance my curly brackets. Only noticed after very careful investigation.

Comment: No problem at all; glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same result by doing the following:

```
var filename = window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$('li.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
$('ul.topnav1 li a[href="' + filename + '"]').parents('li').addClass('highlight');
```

Since you can use the jQuery attribute selector, you can do a strict check and let jQuery do the work, `tag[attribute="value"]`

Comment: i don't get the +filename+ bit.  could you please explain?

Comment: did you mean    .parent('li') instead of parents.('li')      ??

Comment: @ngusum Javascript uses "+" for concatenation. e.g.: If you had two variables like so: `var1 = 'Hello', var2 = 'World';` You could concatonate them using: `var1 + var2`, which would print out: `HelloWorld`
You used `parent().parent()`, instead of doing that, you'd use `parents('[selector]')`, if you know you're only traversing up a single parent, you can use `parent()`.

Comment: Well I used your code, still doesn't work as intended.  I'm at a total loss now.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
  var domain = '{{ DOMAIN }}'; // www.example.com or dev.example.com
  var domain_index =  window.location.href.indexOf(domain);
  var long_app_name = window.location.href.slice(domain_index+domain.length+1); 
  // this turns http://www.example.com/whatever/whatever to whatever/whatever
  app_name = long_app_name.slice(0, long_app_name.indexOf('/')); 
  //now you are left off with just whatever
```

then you use jquery to add class active

$('nav a[href*="' + app_name+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');

and of course the css:

```
.active{background:red;}
```

this works if you have your html like this:

```
<ul><li><a href="ee">ee</a></li><li><a href="dd">dd</a></li></ul>
```

this will atumatically add class active using the page url and color your background to red if your in www.somesite.com/ee thaen ee is the 'app' and it will be active