# How to target a subclass of a class (specially adding and removing this class)

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="active">
    <li><a class="current" href=index.html>About</a></li>
    <li><a href=portfolio.html>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href=essay.html>Essays</a></li>
    <li><a href=resources.html>Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href=research.html>Research</a></li>
    <li id="last"><a href=contact.html>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have used CSS to make the `li` tags into a horizontal list and change color when hovered over.

However, I am trying to make the nav bar present the current active link, which means if I am currently on the index.html, I want the "ABOUT" `li` to be highlighted using the class "current".

And the class current would be applied to the `li` whenever the page is the current page.
After some research, this is the closest thing that I found but it doesn't work.

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $('.active li').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('.nav .current').sublings().removeClass('active')
    });
```

Below is my CSS for these menu navs.

```
.nav li {
  display:inline;
  margin-right:25px;
  font-size:13px;
  padding-top:6px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.active li a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-style:solid;
  border-top-color:#8D919E; 
  border-top-width: 6px;
  padding-top: 6px;
}


.nav .current {
  color:#30B7E7;
  border-top-color:#30B7E7;
}
```

I want to target the .nav .current class somehow and add it to the `li` and remove it from the last `li`.

EDIT: I figured out a super dumb way of doing this through html. I applied the class current to the first LI in for the index page, and the rest do not have this class. And then for the second page, I applied class current to that LI, and removed it from the first one. Its a dumb fix but i cant get any of the JS codes to work for some reason.

Comment: Is .sublings() a typo? You want the li highlighted whenever you're on that page?

Comment: I closed as duplicate, and then reopened because the question to which I linked doesn't have an accepted answer (and I'm somewhat afraid of accidentally abusing near-mod-level powers). I do, though, think it *is* a dupe of that question ([this one, in fact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479513/highlight-current-page-in-navigation-bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479513/highlight-current-page-in-navigation-bar)).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
$('.active li a').on('click', function(e) {
    //prevent the default behaviour of the link 
    //that would have navigated to the next page
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentListEl = $(this).parent("li");//get the a tags parent li
    currentListEl.siblings().removeClass('current');//remove 'current' from its siblings
    currentListEl.addClass('current');//add 'current' to the li

    //navigate to the "current" page or load it with ajax
});
```

Comment: I copy pasted the exact code in a file called script.js, and i linked my original html file to the js document, unfortunately it did not work. Do i have to link this js file to all the different urls of the list? and do i initially set the first list item to have a class of "current"?

Comment: yes, set the first list item to have the class current. Not sure what you mean by link the js to all the different urls of the list. If your not loading content with ajax then I dont think that you need javascript to highlight the current link.

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to the item that matches the page's URL you can do this -

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var currentPage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
$('a[href="' + currentPage + '"]').closest('li').addClass('current active'); // adds highlight to current page element

$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisHREF = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + thisHREF + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `currentPage` will store `http://www.domain.com/page.html` so unless he has that in the href (which would be odd) it won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery is wrong. You're getting a bit lost I think. It should be:

```
$('.active li').on('click',function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');      //<--- Not efficient, but will work
    $(this).children('a').addClass('current'); //<--- You want to add current to a tag?
});
```

Three mistakes I can see are

- `$document.ready(function(){` has a closing `})`? It doesn't in your example.
- Sublings is typo
- Wrong use of `addClass('.nav .current')`. You're not targeting CSS selectors you're adding a class